# Install Ambiance theme in Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, 13.10, ambiance

I installed Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 and want to install the ambiance theme found in the normal saucy distribution. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I installed the packages `light-themes` and `dmz-cursor-theme` for this.